# grunt-closure-tools config issue with multiple targets

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

I want to work with closure compiler, so I added grunt-closure-tools to my Grunt config, but my config is erroring with:

```
Verifying property closureCompiler.loader exists in config...ERROR
```

Here is the reference material for grunt-closure-tools:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-closure-tools

or

https://github.com/thanpolas/grunt-closure-tools

Here is my GruntFile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        var path = require('path');

    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        //pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt'), //path to task.js files, defaults to grunt dir
        init: true, //auto grunt.initConfig
        data: { //data passed into config.  Can use with <%= test %>
             pkg: require('./package.json')
        },
        loadGruntTasks: { //can optionally pass options to load-grunt-tasks.  If you set to false, it will disable auto loading tasks.
            pattern: ['grunt-contrib-*', 'grunt-jslint', 'grunt-newer', 'imagemin-*','grunt-closure-tools'],
            scope: 'devDependencies'
        },
        postProcess: function(config) {} //can post process config object before it gets passed to grunt
    }); 
    //require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["newer:jslint", "newer:concat", "closureCompiler:loader", "newer:sass"]);
};
```

I am using load-grunt-config to break up my config into multiple parts. Here is my closure.js file, mostly modeled on grunt-closure-tools github page example:

```
module.exports = {

  options: {
    compilerFile: '/usr/local/Cellar/closure-compiler/20141023/libexec/build/compiler.jar',
    checkModified: true,

    compilerOpts: {
       create_source_map: null,
       compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
    },
    d32: true, // will use 'java -client -d32 -jar compiler.jar' 
  },

    util: {
            src: 'includes/javascript/util/util.js',
            dest: 'includes/javascript/build/util.min.js'

    },  
    loader: {
            src : 'includes/javascript/loaders/loader.js',
            dest: 'includes/javascript/build/loader.min.js'

    }
};
```

Any help with this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and no small amount of thrashing of teeth, I have managed to getting my config working. My Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        var path = require('path');

    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        //pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt'), //path to task.js files, defaults to grunt dir
        init: true, //auto grunt.initConfig
        data: { //data passed into config.  Can use with <%= test %>
             pkg: require('./package.json')
        },
        loadGruntTasks: { //can optionally pass options to load-grunt-tasks.  If you set to false, it will disable auto loading tasks.
            pattern: ['grunt-contrib-*', 'grunt-jslint', 'grunt-newer', 'imagemin-*','grunt-closure-tools'],
            scope: 'devDependencies'
        },
        postProcess: function(config) {} //can post process config object before it gets passed to grunt
    }); 
    //require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["newer:jslint", "newer:concat", "closureCompiler:loader", "newer:sass"]);
};
```

and my closureCompiler.js file (shortened for clarity):

```
module.exports = {

  options: {
    compilerFile: '/usr/local/Cellar/closure-compiler/20141023/libexec/build/compiler.jar',

    checkModified: true,

    compilerOpts: {

      // create_source_map: null
    },
    execOpts: {

       maxBuffer: 999999 * 1024
    },

    TieredCompilation: true // will use 'java -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -jar compiler.jar' 
  },

    loader: {
        TEMPcompilerOpts: {
            create_source_map: 'includes/javascript/build/loader.min.js.map'
        },
            src : 'includes/javascript/loaders/loader.js',
            dest: 'includes/javascript/build/loader.min.js'
    }
};
```

I had quite a few errors in my config:

1. I had to rename closure.js to closureCompiler.js so load-grunt-config could find the file. Oops, my bad.
2. The d32: true switch on the Closure Compiler means use 32-bit JVM, which I do not have on my system. I switched to TieredCompilation: true instead.
3. create_source_map: null in the options did not work for me. I found the reference in the source code of grunt-closure-tools but didn't spend the time to sort out what was wrong. Instead, I added TEMPcompilerOpts to the target config with the map file I wanted Closure to make.

I hope other benefit from my experience with this solution. From this point, I am going to use the ability of Closure Compiler to create source maps to merge my dev and prod build targets into a single target.